# Java: For Loop and Boolean coding

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, boolean-expression

I am trying to write a Java program that asks the user to enter in the number of students and each of their names and scores, as well as printing out the two students with the highest scores. I have nearly all of it, but I can't get the second highest score. What I have would print out the highest score and the third highest score (with 5 students as input).

Here is part of my code (I didn't want to stretch this out, so I left out the beginning part where the method is first stated, along with importing the scanner. I also left out the last print statement where it prints out the two students and their scores. 
I think the problem is with the if statement near the end, when comparing what the scores are, but I don't know how to make it so it gets the second highest instead of the third.

```
//Prompt user to enter in number of students, each student's name and score
  System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");
  int numberstudents = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the student's name: ");
String name1 = input.next();
System.out.println("Enter the student's score: ");
double score1 = input.nextDouble(); 

String name2 = " ";
double score2 = 0;

//Use a for loop
  for (int data = 0; data < numberstudents - 1; data++){
    System.out.print("Enter the student's name: ");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter the student's score: ");
    double score = input.nextDouble();

//Find which scores are the highest
    if (score > score1) {
    name1 = name;
    score1 = score;
}
    else if (score > score2 && score1 > score) {
    name2 = name;
    score2 = score;
}
```

If you can help me, thank you very much, and even if you can't, thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Shouldn't your for loop be: `for (int data = 0; data < numberstudents; data++) `? (without the -1)

Comment: There was another example looking for one high score, and that was the condition. I think I checked already if I need the -1, and I do.

Answer (score 0):

replace your double if with:

```
if (score > score1) {
    name2 = name1; // store previous max score/name as second
    score2 = score1;

    name1 = name; // store current max score/name as first
    score1 = score;
} else if (score > score2) {
    name2 = name; // current score/name is not max, but can be second max
    score2 = score;
}
```

Comment: This will not work, because it doesn't account for the possibility that the score is the second highest.

Comment: @dasmith you're right, you actually need second if, check updated variant

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student {
    String name;
    double score;
}

LinkedList<Student> students = new LinkedList<Student>();

//then you can have
students.add(new Student(input.next(), input.nextDouble());

Student max;
Student max2;
double score = 0.0;
for (Student s : students) if (s.score >= score) max = s;
students.remove(max);
score = 0.0;
for (Student s : students) if (s.score >= score) max2 = s;

//The top 2 scores are max.score and max2.score
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I haven't learned about lists yet, or whatever method that uses a LinkedList. even if I used this, I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your logic to first check to see if it is larger than the score2 and, if so, store it.  After that, you probably should check to see if it is ALSO larger than score1, and if it is then you should swap score1 and score2.  The way you are doing it now would throw away the highest score if a new high schore comes in, even if the old high score should have been "demoted" to second highest.

Since this is homework, I'll just give pseudocode...

```
if score > score2:
  score2 = score
if score > score1:
  oldScore1 = score1
  score1 = score
  score2 = oldScore1
```

You can refine this and make it a bit more elegant still if you are up for it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

try this! you can get any no of students scores and also prints 1st and 3rd Highest score.

```
    package testing;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Jpro {


@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no. of Students");
    int noOfStudents=in.nextInt();
    String name[]=new String[noOfStudents];
    Double scores[]=new Double[noOfStudents];
    for(int i=0;i<noOfStudents;i++)
    {
            System.out.println("Enter the Student Name:");
            name[i]=in.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the Score of Student:");
            scores[i]=in.nextDouble();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<noOfStudents;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<noOfStudents;j++)
            if(scores[i]>scores[j])
            {
                Double temp=scores[i];String tName=name[i];
                scores[i]=scores[j];name[i]=name[j];
                scores[j]=temp;name[j]=tName;
            }
    }
    System.out.println("1st Highest Scores Name:"+name[0]+"\tScore: "+scores[0]);
    System.out.println("3rd Highest Scores Name:"+name[2]+"\tScore: "+scores[2]);
}
```

}